# Proof of a tr property

Tags: linear-algebra

$Tr(XY) = 1$ and $Tr(Y) = 1$ implies that $Tr(X) = 1$.

I tried to prove by contradiction and switch the dummy variable of $X$ and $Y$. But I don't think my approach is right and if there is any much easier proof.

Answer (score 3):

The property isn't correct. For
$$Y=\begin{pmatrix}0,5&0\\0&0,5\end{pmatrix}, X=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
we have
$$Tr(XY)=Tr(Y)=1$$
but $Tr(X)=2$.